# How to update the model classes when they exist in a separate project

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 (database first).  I split my model classes into a separate project.  I changed my database and updated the edmx diagram.  How do I update my models when they are stored in a separate project?  Do I have to delete and recreate all of the models again?

Comment: by 'model classes', do you mean the mapped database models? or your view models?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be better to put your EDMX diagram into a new project, and then both of the projects you mention could include a reference to this instead?

This would then mean you have one source, instead of the two copies you currently have and any updates will always be up to date for both.